# Change AlertDialog Message with a seek bar

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, seekbar

I have an Alert Dialog but I want to change the message on in depends on the value from the seek bar

[Here's a screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPQP9.jpg)

The Toast do it rigth but I don't know how to implement on the alert dialog message
Here's my code so far

```
public void requestCheckButton(View view){

    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);
    seek.setMax(11); // Para tener incrementos de 5 min

    popDialog.setTitle("¿En cuánto tiempo puedes llegar?");
    popDialog.setMessage("15 min");
    popDialog.setView(seek);
    popDialog.setPositiveButton("Mandar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Presionaste Mandar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progress = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressV, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progressV;
        }


        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

        }


        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Por cada incremento se suman 5 min
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (progress)*5 +"min", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    popDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove popDialog.show();
2. Add **before** seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener

   final AlertDialog dialog = popDialog.create();
3. Instead of toast, call dialog.setMessage();
4. Add dialog.show() at the end

So corrected code:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);
    seek.setMax(11); // Para tener incrementos de 5 min

    popDialog.setTitle("¿En cuánto tiempo puedes llegar?");
    popDialog.setMessage("15 min");
    popDialog.setView(seek);
    popDialog.setPositiveButton("Mandar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Presionaste Mandar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = popDialog.create();
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progress = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressV, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progressV;
        }


        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

        }


        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Por cada incremento se suman 5 min
            dialog.setMessage((progress)*5 +"min");
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a view that contains both, the text view and the seekbar:

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and instead of `setView(seek)`:

```
View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog, null);
final SeekBar seekBar = (Seekbar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
popDialog.setView(view);
```

in your listener:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            textView.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + "");
        }
```

Comment: And you don't have to use setMessage();